# Disallow opponent from offering draw on lichess

Tags: lichess

How can I turn off the ability of the opponent to offer a draw? It has happened a couple of times now. I thought opponent was asking for takeback, in a hugely losing position. But it was actually a draw offer, so I ending up drawing a game that should have been easily won.

Comment: Draw offer is part of the game, if you remove it, it is no longer chess.

Comment: @Ivella So is promoting to a knight, yet many clients have a function to automatically promote to a queen.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni But taking away the opportunity to under promote is restricting what you are allowed to do, and you can always undo it. Taking away the opportunity to offer a draw is restricting what your opponent can do, and they have no way round it. Thus they are fundamentally different.

Comment: @IanBush So you're saying that I cannot have a checkbox that says "forbid opponent to propose draws", but I can have one that says "auto decline draw offers"? Fair enough, I'll take the latter.

Comment: Auto-decline is fine so long as your opponent is informed of it so they don't waste time thinking about and making draw offers. And I have to admit I personally wouldn't play anyone with that option set, but that's my choice.

Comment: @IanBush what's the difference between what you just said and completely forbidding draw offers?

Comment: Honestly the problem is that the takeback confirmation and the draw offer confirmation look identical in lichess. They should be two totally different UIs.

Answer (score 16):

You can't. You can disable takebacks though. If you don't play games long enough with enough time to read what is being asked, perhaps you should accept mouseslips as part of the game.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way you can do this, at least from the options available on Lichess. However, I've put up a [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) script that hides all draw offers such that you have no way to see or accept them:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Lichess - Hide Draw Offers
// @match        https://lichess.org/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';

  var css = ".negotiation.draw { display:none }";
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.innerHTML = css;
  document.head.appendChild(style);

  var chatbox = document.querySelector(".mchat__messages.chat-v-1");
  var options = { childList: true, subtree: true };
  var callback = () => {
    chatbox.querySelectorAll("li.system t").forEach((item) => {
      if(item.innerHTML.indexOf("offers draw") > -1 || item.innerHTML.indexOf("declines draw") > -1) {
        item.parentElement.remove();
      }
    });
  };
  callback();
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(chatbox, options);
})();
```

Note that this does **not** deprive your opponent from their ability to offer you a draw. It just hides the draw offer from you. Your opponent will see their draw offer getting declined as you play your next move.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If your opponent offer you a draw, it means that he already know and understand all the moves you can make to win.

If you take it, it means that you accept your inability to force a victory (to surrender) using another strategy

Comment: lmao I love your username

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by theonlygusti, the actual issue is that the draw offer and the takeback request look identical and are located right in the same spot. It already happened to me multiple times that my opponent requested a takeback with the intention to trick me to clicking accept right when it turns into a draw offer. The first time i didnt consider something like that at all and straight up fell for it . . .